# How do you say the verb "switch/switch to" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

I want to know how you say the idea of "switch to" in Latin. I wasn't able to find a translation

For example if I want to say something like: "I was using this tool, but I switched to a different one" or "Switch to a different weapon" for example

How would you say this concept of "Switch to" in Latin?

Comment: The verb *mutare* can be used in the sense "to put in place of another, to substitute, replace". Try looking that up to see some examples of usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't necessarily a one-to-one correspondence between English and Latin words, but it is true (as MPW said in a comment) that *mutare*, a very versatile verb, will often be useful when talking about things being switched around.

For “switch to a different weapon,” I would not hesitate to simply say *muta telum*. It isn't really necessary to translate “to a different” – it is implied, just as in English you could say “switch weapons” or “change clothes.”

If you want to mention the thing *to which* you switch, you can put it in the ablative, e.g. *illo instrumento utebar, sed alio* [*id*] *mutavi*. You could also use *substituere* (with *pro* if you want), e.g. *forcipe utebar, sed (pro eo) malleum substitui*.

Comment: So for example if I wanted to say a sentence like "Switch to the sword", would I just say "Muta gladio"?

Comment: @Nomad1004 you could, though it should be clear from context that you're talking about the weapon. Or you could just say *utere gladio* or even *sume gladium* (cf. [Ez. 5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ez+5&version=VULGATE)). I mean, "switch to the sword" sounds not exactly like something from Shakespeare, it's video-game language ...